In Polars, how do you create a group counter / group ID?
How do you get a group_id column like this, grouping by columns col1 and col2 ?



col1
col2
group_id




A
Z
1


A
Y
2


A
Z
1


B
Z
3



based on such a DataFrame :
df = pl.DataFrame({
  'col1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B'],
  'col2': ['Z', 'Y', 'Z', 'Z']}
)

In other words, I'm looking for polars equivalent to R data.table .GRP (df[, group_id:=.GRP, by = .(col1, col2)]). Thanks !
Context : I want to build an event ID because in my data, I have many detailed rows for one event. Once the event ID is created, I will use it to perform various window operations. I prefer to have this event ID rather than keeping a list of grouping variables.

Is the order of the ids a strict requirement? pl.struct("col1", "col2").rank("dense") gives ids but they are not ordered by "first seen occurrence".

Thanks @jqurious ! This was enough for me indeed ! And pretty simple. Roman chosed the same solution :)

If you don't care about "first occurrence has lower rank" then you can just rank combination of col1 and col2 columns.

pl.struct() to create one column out of col1, col2.
pl.Expr.rank() to assign rank to rows.

df.with_columns(group_id = pl.struct("col1","col2").rank("dense"))

shape: (4, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬──────────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ group_id │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---      │
│ str  ┆ str  ┆ u32      │
╞══════╪══════╪══════════╡
│ A    ┆ Z    ┆ 2        │
│ A    ┆ Y    ┆ 1        │
│ A    ┆ Z    ┆ 2        │
│ B    ┆ Z    ┆ 3        │
└──────┴──────┴──────────┘

Otherwise, it will be a bit more complicated - you can create index to track current row order and then assign rank based on this index.

pl.DataFrame.with_row_index() to create an index / row number.
pl.Expr.min() and pl.Expr.over() to get minimum index within col, col2.
pl.Expr.rank() to "compress" this minimum to dense rank.

(
    df.with_row_index("group_id")
    .with_columns(
        pl.col.group_id.min().over("col1","col2").rank("dense")
    )
)

shape: (4, 3)
┌──────────┬──────┬──────┐
│ group_id ┆ col1 ┆ col2 │
│ ---      ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ u32      ┆ str  ┆ str  │
╞══════════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1        ┆ A    ┆ Z    │
│ 2        ┆ A    ┆ Y    │
│ 1        ┆ A    ┆ Z    │
│ 3        ┆ B    ┆ Z    │
└──────────┴──────┴──────┘


That's a great answer ! Thank you. The one-liner is enough for me but the other option to keep the ids order is useful too.

One way to do it would be to get a list of unique combinations of col1 and col2 and with an integer row index. That would be the grouping column you are after.
For example:
import polars as pl

# your example
df = pl.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B'],
    'col2': ['Z', 'Y', 'Z', 'Z'],
})

unique_pairs = df.select(['col1', 'col2']).unique().with_row_index(name="group")
df_with_group = df.join(unique_pairs, on=['col1', 'col2'])

print(df_with_group)

The join pairs each row with the appropriate row from unique_pairs and adds the other columns from that row (just group in this case) to the result.
This can result in a different numbering though, if you need the numbering to follow the order in the original data, like in your example, you can change it to:
unique_pairs = (
    df.select(['col1', 'col2'])
    .unique(maintain_order=True)
    .with_row_index(name="group")
)

Now, the unique_pairs will have a numbering of unique pairs that matches the order they first appear in, in df.
Output:
shape: (4, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬───────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ group │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ str  ┆ str  ┆ u32   │
╞══════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ A    ┆ Z    ┆ 0     │
│ A    ┆ Y    ┆ 1     │
│ A    ┆ Z    ┆ 0     │
│ B    ┆ Z    ┆ 2     │
└──────┴──────┴───────┘

However, your question does make me wonder if this is an XY Problem. Why exactly do you need this grouping? Because if the grouping is only generated to perform group operations later, you can just use Polars' grouping functionality.
For example:
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B'],
    'col2': ['Z', 'Y', 'Z', 'Z'],
    'values': [1, 2, 3, 4],       # added some data to operate on
})

grouped_df = df.group_by(['col1', 'col2'], maintain_order=True).agg([
    pl.col('values').sum().alias('sum_values'),
    pl.col('values').mean().alias('mean_values'),
    pl.col('values').count().alias('count_values')
])

print(grouped_df)

Results in:
shape: (3, 5)
┌──────┬──────┬────────────┬─────────────┬──────────────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ sum_values ┆ mean_values ┆ count_values │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---        ┆ ---         ┆ ---          │
│ str  ┆ str  ┆ i64        ┆ f64         ┆ u32          │
╞══════╪══════╪════════════╪═════════════╪══════════════╡
│ A    ┆ Z    ┆ 4          ┆ 2.0         ┆ 2            │
│ A    ┆ Y    ┆ 2          ┆ 2.0         ┆ 1            │
│ B    ┆ Z    ┆ 4          ┆ 4.0         ┆ 1            │
└──────┴──────┴────────────┴─────────────┴──────────────┘


Thanks a lot for your help ! I need to build a new ID, I will add some context to my question. I chose the option of roman without join but yours seem also valid, thanks :)
